# How to update data in CSV files in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Create a stored procedure that will read the .csv file from oracle server path using read file operation, query the data in some X table and write the output in .csv file.

here after read .csv file, compare .csv file data with table data and need to update few columns in .csv file.

Comment: Use utl_file, external tables...many options. Do a search in google/SO and you find many examples.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle works best with data in the database. `UPDATE` is one of the most frequently used commands.

But, modifying a file which resides in some directory seems to be somewhat *out of scope*. There are other programming languages you should use, I believe. However, if a hammer is the only tool you have, every problem looks like a nail.

I can think of two options.

One is to load file into the database. Use SQL*Loader to do that if file resides on your PC, or - if you have access to the database server and DBA granted you read/write privileges on a directory (an Oracle object which points to a filesystem directory) - use  it as an external table. Once you load data, modify it and export it back (i.e. create a new CSV file) using `spool`.

Another option is to use `UTL_FILE` package. It also requires access to the database server's directory. Using the A(ppend) option, you can add rows to the original file, but I don't think that you can *edit* it so this option - at the end - finishes like the previous one - with creating a new file (but this time using `UTL_FILE`).

Conclusion? Don't use a *database management system* to modify *files*. Use another tool.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have followed below steps.

Comment: Please help me.. Still my issue not resolved. I will explain my problem step by step. 1. read the .csv file from oracle server path. 2. .csv file has 3 columns. compare the .csv file data with table data. 3. need to add 2 columns data from table to .csv file 4. need to generate new .csv file and place in oracle server path

Comment: 1. is it possible to add read and write commands in a single stored procedure. 2. can i give directly big path or can I able to create new dir to simplift the path name. 3. if I create a temp table with 5 columns to load data from csv file then I feel I can compare with table data and add remaining 2 columns. data will it work?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. You work with Oracle directory name, which is something *short*. You don't care about its "real" path. 3. I believe it should work.